# Loop not working for urls from csv file

Tags: loops, csv, imacros

Here, the loop not working, only the first url from the csv file is working.I want to run this for all the urls in the csv file, can anyone help me please...

My csv file is like this

https://www.ggogle.com/fhduhfduh, keyword1

https://www.ggogle.com/fdfdfcvxvc, keyword2

https://www.ggogle.com/hghjhjuhjf, keyword3

```
CMDLINE !DATASOURCE C:\Users\User\Desktop\Boo.csv
    SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
    SET !ERRORCONTINUNE YES
    SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
    SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
    SET !LOOP 1
    SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
    TAB T=1
    URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
    FRAME F=0
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN FORM=ID:fght ATTR=TXT:Add
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:fght ATTR=ID:js_2 CONTENT=C:\Users\User\Pictures\01.jpg
    WAIT SECONDS = 15
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TYPE:submit&&CLASS:selected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CMDLINE !DATASOURCE C:\Users\User\Desktop\Boo.csv
    SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
    SET !ERRORCONTINUNE YES
    SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
    SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
    **SET !LOOP 1** <-- YOUR PROBLEM
    SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
    TAB T=1
    URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
    FRAME F=0
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN FORM=ID:fght ATTR=TXT:Add
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:fght ATTR=ID:js_2 CONTENT=C:\Users\User\Pictures\01.jpg
    WAIT SECONDS = 15
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TYPE:submit&&CLASS:selected
```

If you set the !LOOP to 1, then it will only read the first line of the file. Either set it to how many lines you have in your csv file or delete it and input the number of loops when you play the macro.